# Is there a reference for MaskEdit's masks?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, maskedtextbox

I'm trying to make a semi-complex masking textbox in Delphi 7. I'm having problems in that I can't find any kind of reference for what each character in a mask means. All I can find are examples.

Is there a reference somewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this [topic from the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) has the most complete list of characters.

The same topic can be found in your Delphi 7 help file by searching for TMaskEdit. I just checked the Delphi 6 help file and the list of mask characters is identical to the XE2 version so, as @afrazier says, nothing much appears to have changed.

Comment: +1 - As far as I know, this hasn't changed much since Delphi 7.  It's in the D7 Help under `TEditMask type` in the `MaskUtils` Unit.